# Show that $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x^{2}+1 \rangle}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ without using fundamental theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, field-theory, equivalence-relations

The task is to prove that $\dfrac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x^2+1\rangle}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ without using the fundamental theorem, and insteadusing equivalence classes, with the relation $p(x)\sim q(x)$ if $p-q \in N$, where $N$ is the set of polynomials divisible by $x^2+1$.

The equivalence classes looks like $[ax+b]$. The function $f$ is defined from equivalence classes to $\mathbb{C}$ as $f(a+bx)=a+ib$.

I'm stuck at prove the condition $f([p] \cdot [q])=f([p])\cdot f([q])$.
Suppose $p(x)=ax+b$ and $q(x)=cx+d$, then we have to prove $f(acx^{2}+(ad+bc)x+bd)=(a+ib)\cdot (c+id)$. But I stuck here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which fundamental theorem are you trying to avoid? In particular, can you use the first isomorphism theorem for rings?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: Pretty darn sure that is the "fundamental theorem" being referred to; it's often called the "fundamental theorem of homomorphisms"...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin -- I've never heard it called that, but I also thought that was what OP meant. That's why I wanted to clarify.

Comment: Note that if $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ (don't rush to restrict yourself only to polynomials of degree at most $1$. Every equivalence class indeed has such representative, but it doesn't mean you can't use other representatives) then your map sends $[p]$ to $p(i)$. Now you can easily show it is a homomorphism, using the fact that substitution of $i$ is a homomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x]\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I don't see the additional value to avoid such a basic fundamental theorem.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: It took until after I got my degree to see it called that. It isn't exactly the first isomorphism theorem, but the more general one that if $f\colon A\to B$ is a morphism (groups/rings) and $N\triangleleft A$ is contained in $\ker(f)$, then $f$ factors through $A/N$.

Comment: @Mark but my function is correct right? If not where am I missing?

Comment: @Mark Moreover, the function is indeed an evaluation map.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Coz it is a exercise given in real analysis book.

Comment: It is correct, but you restricted yourself to polynomials of degree at most $1$, which complicates the definition a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, in $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, $x^2=-1$. So,$$acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd=(ad+bc)x+bd-ac,$$and therefore\begin{align}f\bigl((ax+b)(cx+d)\bigr)&=f\bigl(acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd\bigr)\\&=f\bigl((ad+bc)x+bd-ac\bigr)\\&=(ad+bc)i+bd-ac\\&=(ai+b)(ci+d).\end{align}